# List of phrasal verbs by approximate usage frequency?

Tags: discussion

I have found two sources of lists of phrasal verbs in English: Textbooks for people learning English as a second language introduce a few of them every now and then, and dictionaries of phrasal verbs list thousands of them in alphabetical order.

English-speaking people are of course unaware of English grammar just as a fish is unaware of water. (A really extreme case I found on the internet was someone who asserted that translation is the process of replacing each word in one language with the corresponding word in another language.) The purpose of having a variety of illustrative examples adapted to the context at hand when explaining something about usage is not well served by those kinds of sources. What could serve that purpose well is lists of maybe a couple of hundred most frequently used phrasal verbs in English, with the most frequently used ones first.

Do such lists exist?

Comment: Maybe searching for `VERB PREP` in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) or similar would work?

Comment: Googling *most common phrasal verbs* gives lots of example lists. You don't specify how authoritative you want the list to be; have you read the lists and rejected them? Do you require specific usage rankings/scores, or just the top 200?

Comment: The lists you find on line themselves are inherently choosing what they think are the most important and what they presume are the most important. Smaller lists will tend to have the most important/frequent, and dropping those from the larger lists will give less frequent ones. In other words you can figure out the order, but I doubt you'll find a reference that orders them explicitly by frequency. You can find or extract (with programming) frequency lists for single words, but phrase frequency, especially where the parts are not adjacent, are not currently easy to automate.

Comment: There are dictionaries of phrasal verbs. [George Meyer's](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110822106/html?lang=en) went through every verb in an unabridged dictionary and associated it with every possible particle.

Comment: @JohnLawler : You might notice that the posted question itself says there are dictionaries of phrasal verbs and explains why they don't serve the purpose efficiently.

Comment: Dictionaries don't give usage frequencies. Those have to be determined by researchers individually, according to their own standards of "frequency". But a dictionary or other complete list is the place to start before you start sorting through texts.